# Dependency injection - Instance Lifetime for .Net MVC 5 webapps - Unity Container

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I'm trying to have a better understanding of the lifetime of objects in DI by the point of view of an webapp. I'm using `Unity Container`  [docs here](http://unitycontainer.org/tutorials/lifetime/lifetime.html).

**Singleton**

> Singleton lifetime creates globally unique singleton. Any Unity
> container tree (parent and all the children) is guaranteed to have
> only one global singleton for the registered type.

Now, because I've read so many articles, I've come to understand that `Singleton` is a instance that is created once and used for the `entire life of application`. What does this mean having in mind that 2 users use my app in the same time(or not) from different PCs - does this mean that if this instance is a variable, it will be common for all users for the entire time my app is hosted on the server (or until app `App Pool Recycle`)?

In my app I use different services that are injected in the controllers constructor.

1. Will `Singleton` be suited for an instance of a log service, or a DbContext instance?
2. If I use it for a DbContext instance, and something get's modified in the my Db structure - this instance will update?

**Per Container**

> Per Container lifetime allows a registration of an existing or
> resolved object as a scoped singleton in the container it was created
> or registered. In other words this instance is unique within the
> container it was registered with. Child or parent containers could
> have their own instances registered for the same contract.

Same case: If 2 users use my app in the same time and visit same Controller, does this mean that they share the same instance of a `Per Container` variable/service?

Hope these questions have some meaning and I don't simply overthink it. Thank you!